# R: How to pass rVector through java in connection eval () function

Tags: java, r, soapui

**R Code**

```
abc <- function(theta,y) {
    a <- y[1]
    b <- y[2]
    c <- y[3]
    p <- c/(1+(a*(theta-b)))
    return(p) 
}
```

**Java Code**

```
RConnection connection = new RConnection();
connection.eval("source('D:\\\\file.R')");
double theta = 7
double a = 5
double b = 9
double c = 2
double y = "c(a,b,c)" // 'y' is R vector of length 3 (one-dimensional array) 
with a, b, and c parameters as elements
double sum = connection.eval("abc("+theta+","+y+")")
log.info("The sum is=" + sum);
```

**Problem**

I want to pass vector (y) on eval function but not able to do that. Is there any way to do that ??

Comment: May be you need to `paste` i.e. `paste0("abc(", theta, y, ")")`

Comment: It is still not working.